# How to calculate throughput for each node.

Tags: veins

I am working on a network congestion control algorithm and I would like to get the fairness, more specifically Jain's fairness index.

However I need to get the throughput of each node or vehicle. 
I know the basic definition of throughput in networks, which is the amount of data transferred over a period of time.

I am not sure what the term means in vehicular network due to the nature of the network being broadcast only.

My current set up, the only message transmitted is BSM with a rate of 10Hz.

Using: Omnet++ 5.1.1 VEINS 4.6 and SUMO 0.30

Thank you.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't read the title.. Lets erase these comments..

Comment: @JulianHeinovski You had me thinking maybe about the question I am asking if it is a legitimate question. Any how, any inputs on this?

Comment: I guess you should start by figuring out what fairness means in vehicular networks. There should be plenty of literature on this.